# Classification of degree (bi-)sequences of bipartite graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

It is known that the sequence $d_1 \geq d_2 \geq \ldots \geq d_n$ of nonnegative integers is the degree sequence of a graph if and only if the sum of the $d_i$ is even and we have
\[
\sum_{i = 1}^k d_i \leq k(k - 1) + \sum_{i = k + 1}^n \min(d_i, k)
\]
for all $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.  (This is the Erdős–Gallai theorem.)  There is also a simple algorithm (the Havel-Hakimi algorithm) for producing a graph with a given valid degree sequence.

> Is there a simple characterization of pairs $\{(a_1 \geq \ldots \geq a_m), (b_1 \geq \ldots \geq b_n)\}$ of sequences of nonnegative integers such that there exists a bipartite graph with the property that the degrees of the vertices in one part are given by the $a_i$ and the degrees of the vertices in the other part is given by the $b_j$?

An obvious necessary condition is that $\sum a_i = \sum b_j$, but this is also clearly not sufficient.  One can also ask for an algorithm analogous to Havel-Hakimi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you are looking for the [Gale-Ryser theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gale-RyserTheorem.html). There is a version of Havel-Hakimi for bipartite graphs as well. It says that the pair $(P,Q)$ is bigraphic if and only if the pair $(P',Q')$ is bigraphic, where $(P', Q')$ is obtained from $(P, Q)$ by deleting the largest element $p_1$ of $P$ and subtracting one from each of the $p_1$ largest elements of $Q$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this version of the Havel-Hakimi construction?

Comment: @SzabolcsHorvát See exercise 1.4.32 of _Introduction to Graph Theory_, by D.B. West.

Answer (score 3):

This is only a semi-answer: The existence of such a graph is equivalent to finding the maximal flow in a network where the source is connected to all the "red" vertices by edges of capacities $a_1, \dots, a_n$, the sink is connected to all the "blue" vertices by edges of capacity $b_1, \dots, b_n$ and every blue edge is connected to every red edge by an edge of capacity $1.$ If the maximal flow equals $\sum a_i = \sum b_j,$ then the degree sequence exists. Finding such a flow is quite fast (see, eg, Ahuja and Orlin's book on network flow).

Comment: Presumably the max-flow min-cut theorem can be transformed into a characterization of the valid degree sequences.

Comment: There might be some strengthening of the Hall Marriage Theorem, but it does not jump out at me :(

Answer (score -2):

Potentially and forcibly bigraphic sequences are characterized by T. Gangopadhyay way back in eighties.

Comment: Could you give a reference?